# GCC Flag to SCONS

Tags: c++, scons

I`m building a library using *make* with the following flags:

```
INCL = `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib64/pkgconfig:/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig:/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags ipopt` $(ADDINCFLAGS)

LIBS = 
 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/mingw64/lib64/pkgconfig:/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig:/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig pkg-config --libs ipopt'
```

How can I translate this to build with SCONS ?

My issue is to understand how the path definition `PKG_CONFIG_PATH= ...` is passed to SCONS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you'll want to use either ParseFlags() or MergeFlags()

See:
http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html

Further there's a reasonable example in the SCons wiki here:
https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/UsingPkgConfig

Comment: Thank you, `env.ParseConfig('pkg-config --cflags --libs ipopt')` solved for me. Also installing the toolchain version of pkg-config (using mingw64: (`mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`)